# Multicolumn is resulting in bad table format

Tags: tables

I am trying to draw a table in latex. Following is the code

```
    \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc|cccc}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for images } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for videos} \\
        NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP & NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP\\
        \hline
        1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
        \hline
\label{run}
\end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
```

The table that I get is as follows:[image]

The subheadings 'NITRA, etc' are not aligned properly. Also, the heading 'Averages total.....' should be in a two line format for legibility. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide the complete code next time. You must have messed up something in the rest of the code; the code you posted does not produce this table, were the line touches the numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Avoid `\resizebox` if you can and, in this case, you do.

Use a row for the common information and another one for the additional bits; with `\cmidrule` it becomes apparent what are the affected columns.

Using `siunitx` allows for better appearance; set the figures in `table-format` according to your particular values.

I computed the length in `\addtolength` by first typesetting the table with the default value of `\tabcolsep`, then divided the amount of overfilling by 14 (the number of intercolumn spaces). If the shrinking is excessive (above 4pt, I'd say), insert `\small` before `\begin{tabular}` and retry. In particularly tough cases, `\footnotesize` should solve the issue. Smaller type size would make the table unreadable, and you should rethink how to present it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed
  Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}\label{run}

\addtolength\tabcolsep{-1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Averaged total runtime (in \si{\second}) of different algorithms} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{for images} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{for videos}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-4}\cmidrule(l){5-8}
{NITRA} & {CoSaMP} & {OMP} & {StOMP} & {NITRA} & {CoSaMP} & {OMP} & {StOMP} \\
\midrule
1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For instance, if the data are just one row, it would be much preferable to organize the table in a different way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed
  Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}\label{run}

\addtolength\tabcolsep{-1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Averaged total runtime (in \si{\second})} \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{of different algorithms} \\
\midrule
& {images} & {videos} \\
\midrule
NITRA  &  1.3067 &  10.4523 \\
CoSaMP &  2.5134 &  14.7223 \\
OMP    & 11.8195 &  73.2695 \\
StOMP  & 19.5301 & 124.7040 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\parbox{.4\textwidth}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for images }} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\parbox{.4\textwidth}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for videos}} \\
        NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP & NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP\\
        \hline
        1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
        \hline
\label{run}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I implemented your code and I get the same result as yours but the table exceeds the textwidth on the right side.

Comment: I used `\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` before `\begin{tabular}` and this solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc|cccc}
\toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\parbox{.4\textwidth}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for images }} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\parbox{.4\textwidth}{Averaged total runtime (s) of different algorithms for videos}} \\
        \midrule
        NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP & NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP\\
        \midrule
        1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and the resulting table is perfect. But the table exceeds the text width. What should I do for that?

Comment: I used `\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` before `\begin{tabular}` and this solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I propose one of these variations on @gernot's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage{multido} %

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{format=hang}
  \centering
  \caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed
    Videos\\ using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}\label{run}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0.3em}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{9}{c}{Averaged total runtime (in s) of different algorithms} \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{for images}
    & \raisebox{0pt}{\smash{\color{Lavender!75! lightgray}\rule[-8.5ex]{1.5em}{10ex}}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{for videos}\\[1ex]
    NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP & & NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP \\
    \arrayrulecolor{Lavender!75! lightgray}\cmidrule[1.6\heavyrulewidth]{1-4} \cmidrule[1.6\heavyrulewidth]{6-9}
    1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301
    & & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{format=hang}
  \centering
  \caption{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed
    Videos\\ using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}\label{run}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0.3em}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{9}{c}{Averaged total runtime (in s) of different algorithms} \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{for images}
    & \raisebox{0pt}{{\color{Lavender!60!lightgray}\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{\smash{\rule[-8.5ex]{1pt}{10ex}}\,}\negthinspace}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{for videos}\\[1ex]
    NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP & & NITRA & CoSaMP & OMP & StOMP \\
    \arrayrulecolor{Lavender!60!lightgray}\cmidrule[1.6\lightrulewidth]{1-4} \cmidrule[1.6\lightrulewidth]{6-9}
    1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301
    & & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd contract the common parts of the two headlines. Moreover, don't use `[H]` with `table`, since a `table` is meant to float around. If you want the table to stay in place, use the `capt-of` or `caption` package to get a caption. If the table almost fits the page, you can gain some space by reducing the column separation using `\setlength\tabcolsep{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \captionof{table}{Objective Measures for the Quality of Reconstructed
    Videos using NITRA, OMP and STOMP}\label{run}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0.4em}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Averaged total runtime (in s) of different algorithms} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{for images} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{for videos}\\
    NITRA  & CoSaMP & OMP     & StOMP 
        & NITRA   & CoSaMP  & OMP     & StOMP\\
    \midrule
    1.3067 & 2.5134 & 11.8195 & 19.5301 
        & 10.4523 & 14.7223 & 73.2695 & 124.7040 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]